# Store css variables in db and send to frontend in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I have an app serving many clients. Each of these clients has an account based on `Client` model. Each of these clients also has a particular css stylesheet. All these clients have only one html.erb file with variables for each client. But each of these clients have different css files. What I would like to do is to make one css file for all these clients just like the html file with variables. So I have another model called `ClientConfiguration` that has all the configurations necessary for that particular client.

My question is if I store variables like `background`, `image`, `navbar-color` through a form in database in `ClientConfiguration` model instance of that particular `Client`, can I access them in the css.erb file? If yes, is it similar to how the variables are sent to html.erb files? Also is it a good practice? This method is not possible because of assets precompilation. So how can I make it work? I think this is not the Rails way. Can anyone suggest me a solution to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I think you can try doing something like this in your `application.html.erb` file or in `index.html.erb` file

```
  <style type="text/css">
    <%= current_user.css_content %>
  </style>
```

Comment: Ok. I will try it but what according to you would be the best approach?